# How to restrict query of a ManyToMany relationship with Q.AND in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to get all images that have 2 specific tags, 'tag1' `AND` 'tag2'. My simplified models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, null=True, blank=True)
```

Concatenating `filter` works:

```
query = Image.objects.filter(tag__name='tag1').filter(tag__name='tag2')
```

However, I thought I could do it using the Q object from Django. I'm building a complex query, so using Q would be more straightforward. I'm adding all parameters to a `qobj = Q()` using `qobj.add(Q(tag__name='tag1'), Q.AND)`. But... the following retrieves nothing:

```
qobj = Q()
qobj.add(Q(tag__name='tag1'), Q.AND)
qobj.add(Q(tag__name='tag2'), Q.AND)
query = Image.objects.filter(qobj)
```

Everything works as expected when using `OR` connector in the code above, returning correctly images that have tag1 `OR` tag2.

It seems that in the `AND` case it is looking for a row in app_tag_images with both tags, which is obviously absent, since each row has only one tag_id for a image_id.

Is there a way to build this query with Q?

ps: let me know if more details of the code are needed.

**edit:**

Here is que sql query of the query with Q (I cleaned most `SELECT` columns for clarity):

```
SELECT "meta_image"."id", "meta_image"."title"
FROM "meta_image"
INNER JOIN "meta_tag_images" ON ("meta_image"."id" = "meta_tag_images"."image_id")
INNER JOIN "meta_tag" ON ("meta_tag_images"."tag_id" = "meta_tag"."id")
WHERE ("meta_tag"."name" = tag1 AND "meta_tag"."name" = tag2)
```

`OR` query is identical as above (replacing `AND` by `OR`).

Just for reference, the working method using filter concatenating prints this query (also simplified):

```
SELECT "meta_image"."id", "meta_image"."title"
FROM "meta_image"
INNER JOIN "meta_tag_images" ON ("meta_image"."id" = "meta_tag_images"."image_id")
INNER JOIN "meta_tag" ON ("meta_tag_images"."tag_id" = "meta_tag"."id")
INNER JOIN "meta_tag_images" T4 ON ("meta_image"."id" = T4."image_id")
INNER JOIN "meta_tag" T5 ON (T4."tag_id" = T5."id")
WHERE ("meta_tag"."name" = tag1 AND T5."name" = tag2)
```

Comment: Is this your own tag implementation or are you using a library like tagging or taggit?

Comment: It is my own tag model, no external app.

Comment: FWIW - 10 years later, just came across this as well. Chaining Q() &= Q() for manytomany... The only way to get it work is to chain .filter().

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't even aware of that format!

What's wrong with the way the docs show Q object usage? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

`Image.objects.filter(Q(tag__name='tag1') & Q(tag__name='tag2'))`

**UPDATE**:
I tested the qobj.add() method on my model with m2m and it works fine on 1.2.3

It also works fine copy and pasting your simplified model.

Are you sure your query is supposed to return something?

Does the standard Q usage `Q(tag__name='tag1') & Q(tag__name='tag2')` return results?

Can you print `myquery.query` as well?

Let's narrow this down.

Comment: Hey, no, the standard way above does not return results. The only way I managed to get the right result is by concatenating filter. The printed query for the standard format and qobj method is identical (both different from filter concat way). I'm going to edit the post and paste the queries.